# Rails and multiple database in backend

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, performance

I currently have a Rails application which is configured with one `MySQL` database.

The problem is that database size grows very rapidly. Roughly `~3,500,000` records every 3 months and `1 GB` in size.

Although, proper indexing is applied, the app seemed to be working as expected until recently where the queries to database started to timeout.

Am I really stretching the limits of MySQL here? Is there any Rails plugin I can use to allow my same code to work with multiple databases in the backed so that one DB server doesn't get burdened?

What would you do in such situation?

Answer (score 0):

you might try [partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning.html) the database

Comment: Partitioning mysql innodb is somewhat limiting, you cannot use foreign keys from the partitioned table, or refer to the partitioned table from other tables.

Answer (score 0):

The size you are describing here is by no means too large for one mysql instance. A few million rows and a total size of a a few G's is not so bad. There is a lot a performance gains you can get by simply tuning your configurations. Are you using Innodb? If so take a hard look at your my.cnf file and pay close attention to you innodb_buffer_pool_size. Also, what is your access patten? multiple reads, few writes ? multiple writes a few reads? both ? You can add a caching layer like memcached. In case of multiple reads, you can add replication slaves. In short, there may be some runway for you before you have to shard you database.